# Как просто заполнить пустой массив данными в цикле?

Tags: javascript, php, массивы

Никак не могу понять как мне наполнить многомерный массив при переборе данных в **JS** так же просто как в **PHP**.
Там я это делал одной строке в цикле, независимо от данных, которые у меня есть до перебора.

```
$newArray = [] // пусто

foreach ($item as $item) {

    $newArray[$item['param1']][$item['param2']][$item['param3']][] = $item['param4'] 

}
```

На выходе готовый массив. **JS** же уже весь мозг вынес со своими *undefined*

такая вложенность получается

```
[
    [param1] => [
        [param2] => [
            [param3] => [
                [0] => param4
                [1] => param4
            ],
            [param3] => [
                [0] => param4
            ],
        ],
        [param2] => [
            [param3] => [
                [0] => param4
            ],
        ],
    ],
    ....
]
```

Есть ли какое то простое решение?

Comment: Добавить новый элемент в конец массива можно методом [push(...elements)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Добавить новый элемент в начало массива можно методом [unshift(...elements)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). Объединить элементы нескольких массивов можно методом [concat(...arrays)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Изменить какой-либо элемент можно оператором присвоения.

Answer (score 2):

То, что в PHP называется массивами, в JSON делится на две части: массивы `[]` и объекты `{}`. Массив - это такая коллекция элементов, где для доступа к элементам используется порядковый номер *(индекс)* элемента. Объект - это такая коллекция элементов, где для доступа к элементам используется строковое имя *(свойство объекта)* элемента. В PHP и то и другое - есть массивы. Поэтому, в JS массивы и объекты управляются немного по-разному.

Аналогом циклов PHP

```
foreach($array as $item){ 
  /* Тут в $array будет ссылка на массив
         в $item будет копия текущего элемента */
}

foreach($array as $index => $item){ 
  /* Тут в $array будет ссылка на массив
         в $index будет индекс или ключ элемента
         в $item будет копия текущего элемента */
}
```

в JS будет для массивов:

```
for(const item of array){
  /* Тут в array будет ссылка на массив
         в item будет ссылка на текущий элемент */
}

for(const [index, item] of array.entries()){
  /* Тут в array будет ссылка на массив
         в item будет ссылка на текущий элемент 
         в index будет индекс элемента */
}
```

и для объектов:

```
for(const [propertyKey, propertyValue] of Object.entries(object)){
  /* Тут в object будет ссылка на объект
         в propertyKey будет название текущего свойства
         в propertyValue будет значение текущего свойства */
}
```

Приведу пример. Чтобы создать объект со структурой JSON как здесь:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

можно просто сгенерировав такой код:

```
const header = {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Либо, если json находится в строке, можно использовать `JSON.parse()`

```
const header = JSON.parse('{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File",\
"popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},\
{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},\
{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}')
```

Либо, если генерировать объект частями, формально эквивалентно предыдущим вариантам будет такой:

```
const header = {};
header.menu = {};
header.menu.id = "file";
header.menu.value = "File";
header.menu.popup = {};
header.menu.popup.menuitem = [];
header.menu.popup.menuitem[0] = {};
header.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value = "New";
header.menu.popup.menuitem[0].onclick = "CreateNewDoc()";
header.menu.popup.menuitem[1] = {};
header.menu.popup.menuitem[1].value = "Open";
header.menu.popup.menuitem[1].onclick = "OpenDoc()";
header.menu.popup.menuitem[2] = {};
header.menu.popup.menuitem[2].value = "Close";
```